# T SQL SELECT statement with complex CASE in WHERE clause

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am trying to select * from a table, but the range of selection is dependent on the inputted Month.

I use CASE in my WHERE clause to determine the Month Value, and choose the right Where statement.

However I get an error;

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AND'.

Here is my SQL statement:

```
select * from MyTable
where Station = 'MyStation' 
and  case when @Month > 9 then

(CONVERT(DATE, CommittedDate, 103) BETWEEN 

CAST(@Year as varchar(10))+ '1001' AND CAST(@Year as varchar(10))+ REPLACE(STR(@Month, 2), ' ', '0')+'25')

else

(CONVERT(DATE, CommittedDate, 103) BETWEEN 

CAST(@Year as varchar(10))+ '1001' AND CAST(@Year as varchar(10))+ REPLACE(STR(@Month, 2), ' ', '0')+'25')
```

I have tried putting `CASE` after the `BETWEEN`, to filter just the values in between, but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really need a case statement here.  You should be able to do it like this:

```
select * from MyTable
where Station = 'MyStation'
and ((@Month > 9 AND
        (CONVERT(DATE, CommittedDate, 103) BETWEEN
            CAST(@Year as varchar(10))+ '1001' AND CAST(@Year as varchar(10))+ REPLACE(STR(@Month, 2), ' ', '0')+'25'))
    OR (@Month <= 9
            (CONVERT(DATE, CommittedDate, 103) BETWEEN
               CAST(@Year as varchar(10))+ '1001' AND CAST(@Year as varchar(10))+ REPLACE(STR(@Month, 2), ' ', '0')+'25')))
```

Comment: Not supposed to say thanks, but it worked great, and I am grateful. I like the solution :)

Answer (score 1):

In your particular example, you don't (and shouldn't) need to put that in the `WHERE` to begin with.  It can be calculated before the query and stored into a variable.